# Programmatically convert text to phonetic TTS readable text?

Tags: python, ruby, text-to-speech

I would like to take snippets of text and convert them, programmatically, to be more phonetic than traditional English spellings.  The purpose of this is for converting a bunch of text I'm working with to a version that can be read by common TTS tools in a more natural way for a scientific application.

Many of the terms and acronyms are common, but there are a variety that are not.  I am hoping to find a script or resource of some kind that already has much of this effort done (realizing I will have to do a bit of customization as per these terms), however so far I've found nothing that goes down this path.

I HAVE found solutions that are *truly* phonetic and are for linguistic applications, however these are not desirable as they are not readable by standard off the shelf TTS solutions that I've used.

Any ideas of a starting point for this situation?  Any examples or even libs that make this easier to chew would be fine.  Or am I bound to sit down and grind out a solution entirely of my own design?

Comment: So, for example, you want to programmatically turn 'differentiation' into 'difurenteeaychun'. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes @NickODell, you've got it right essentially. I've found that I'm having to also add a lot of commas and multiple periods to alter pronunciation and to add proper pauses as well manually right now for Twilio and it's becoming a real problem.

Comment: have you seen http://www.phonetizer.com/

Comment: or these coding guidelines - http://www.coding-guidelines.com/slike/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea that should work :

1. Use a cunning, "linguist"-grade phoneticizer.
2. Use a standard, small table of phonetic to English syllable  ( in the English accent of your choosing ), mappings.
3. Run the resulting "phonetically spelled" words through a standard, OTS TTS product .

So, for example, you can have :

Fish and chips ----step 1---> phonetic linguist code ---step 2. (new Zealand accent)---> fush und chupsh ---step 3. ---> audio pleasure

Hope this assists you!